# Swift dynamic cast failed with HTTP GET request

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, http-get

After creating an app with RubyMotion, this is my first experience with developing apps in Swift with xCode.

I use the following code to get all the posts from an Rails API, the request is successful but parsing the JSON gives an error.

The code:

```
func loadData() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/posts")
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        var err: NSError?
        var json =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

The error:

```
libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional:
0x103dbae20:  pushq  %rbp
0x103dbae21:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x103dbae24:  pushq  %rbx
0x103dbae25:  pushq  %rax
0x103dbae26:  movq   %rsi, %rcx
0x103dbae29:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x103dbae2c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
0x103dbae2e:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
0x103dbae31:  je     0x103dbae4d               ;     swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional + 45
0x103dbae33:  movq   0x72b66(%rip), %rsi       ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x103dbae3a:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
0x103dbae3d:  movq   %rcx, %rdx
0x103dbae40:  callq  *0x5e212(%rip)            ; (void *)0x0000000105b6f000: objc_msgSend
0x103dbae46:  testb  %al, %al
0x103dbae48:  movq   %rbx, %rax
0x103dbae4b:  je     0x103dbae54               ;     swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional +     52
0x103dbae4d:  addq   $0x8, %rsp
0x103dbae51:  popq   %rbx
0x103dbae52:  popq   %rbp
0x103dbae53:  retq   
0x103dbae54:  leaq   0xe427(%rip), %rax        ; "Swift dynamic cast failed"
0x103dbae5b:  movq   %rax, 0x7974e(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
0x103dbae62:  int3   
0x103dbae63:  nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share JSON that you receive? I assume that you receive an array of objects, so you should cast to `NSArray`.

Comment: It was indeed an array of objects. With changing NSDictionary to NSArray the problem is solved. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your URL `http://localhost:3000/api/posts` I can assume that you receive an array of objects, so you should be casting the result to NSArray.

Code should be:

```
var json =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSArray
```

However as mentioned by Yatheesha, you can receive nil so it is better to cast to nullable array and check in `if let...`:

```
if let json =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray { 
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case data may be `nil` then you will get `nil` from `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` so type casting leads to crash, Try this

```
 func loadData() {
     let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api/posts")
     let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
         var err: NSError?
         if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray {

               //Valid NSArray object
          }
         else {
            //NSArray is nil
         }
           })
        task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the app isn't crashing anymore but still don't get an result. By using the advice of Keenie, it is now working. Also thanks for the quick reply!